# Future.wait() - Get the Successful Responses Anyway

Tags: http, flutter, dart, future

I have a list of futures which I want to get its responses, and each future should fail after 10 seconds:

```
  List<Future<http.Response>> futuresList = new List<Future<http.Response>>();

  for (final blog in blogsList) {
    futuresList.add(http.get(blog.rssURL).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10)));
  }

  try {
    List<http.Response> responses = await Future.wait(futuresList);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Futures list error: " + e.toString());
  }
```

My problem is the natural behaviour of the `wait()` function - even when only one of the futures throws an exception, all of the others gets lost and the code gets into the `catch` block...

**Is there a way to get all of the responses and detect which one was successful it which wasn't?**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you can check the response of the http get request before adding it to your list , if the response code is not 200 (which means that http get was not successful) add it as failed to your list. You can then iterate over the list to know which requests were successful and which were not

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: Yes but before I do that , is it okay if my example does not use the wait() function? When I first read your question I figured that I can just perform the get requests and then add them to the list. Instead of making a list of futures , adding them and then executing it , I want to make a list of urls execute them one by one and then add their response to the list of responses. Will that fit your requirement or have I misunderstood ?

Comment: It would not fit my requirement because my goal is to make all of the requests together and save valuable time, rather than one after the other.